# ggrepel change the segments

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Trying to add labels to my points with jitter point.
I defined the position using pos and use geom_label with pos instead off jitter.
That works well but the point of doing that was then to add labels to some of my points.
I use geom_text_repel (also tried with geom_label_repel) but don't manage to get appropriate labelling.
As you can see on my figure, the segments are doing weird stuff, especially for PDAC104.
What would be the option to have the segment from the label to the point (exactly to the point, not mm away like here).
I tried the different padding options but had not manage to have things working.

Thanks,

M

```
my.label <- stat_ind_pi1_ok %>% filter(Pop1=="Is" | ID=="PDAC64")
pos <- position_jitter(width = 0.2, seed=1)
Plot_pi1_indPop <- stat_ind_pi1_ok %>% filter(Pop1=="bla" | Pop1=="ME" | Pop1=="Nafr" | Pop1=="Is") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pop1, y = mean_pi_pc, colour = Pop1)) +
    geom_point(position = pos, alpha=0.35, size=2) +
    geom_text_repel(data=my.label, mapping=aes(label=ID), position=pos, label.size = NA, fill = NA, size=3,
                     max.overlaps = Inf, min.segment.length=0, box.padding=0.5, label.padding=0, point.padding=0) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", size = 5) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_color_hue() +
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Pi (%)") +
    theme_light() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none",
      axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
      panel.grid = element_blank()
    ) ; Plot_pi1_indPop
```

[image: My plot]I

Comment: I think [this explanation may be what you need](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/123#issuecomment-443220041).

Comment: FYI, a nicer way to write `Pop1=="bla" | Pop1=="ME" | Pop1=="Nafr" | Pop1=="Is"` is `Pop1 %in% c("bla", "ME", "Nafr", "Is")`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting - thanks for your question.  Your code and approach to your plot are not to blame here, but rather it is the way in which `position_jitter()` is applied to a dataset.  The object created from `position_jitter()` can basically be thought of as an array of jitter values that is applied row-by-row to your dataset.  Mind you, I'm not *exactly* sure if that's really what's going on, but the behavior matches that way of working.

#### Identifying the Issue

So, what's going on here?  Well, first let me create a dummy dataset to use as an example.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
```

I'll plot the dataset and apply a pre-created `position_jitter()` object to `geom_point()` and to `geom_text_repel()`.  You'll see the output plot has all segments matching up to the points as you would expect.

```
pos <- position_jitter(width=0.5, seed=1)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(position=pos) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=x), color='red', position=pos, force=20)
```

[image]

The issues become apparent if we have `geom_point()` apply to the entire dataset, but apply `geom_text_repel()` to a subset of that dataset (which is basically your own case).

```
df_rep <- df %>% dplyr::filter(x > 5)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(position=pos) +
  geom_text_repel(data=df_rep, aes(label=x), color='red', position=pos, force=20)
```

[image]

Now the segments do not line up, which is what you observe.  The key here is to understand that `pos` is not at all linked to the datasets used for plotting.  If you think of it as a numeric vector that gets multiplied by the x aesthetic before plotting, the behavior makes a bit of sense.  *The first observation in the full dataset is adjusted by the same value that the first set in the subset is adjusted, but that means that specific observations are not jittered the same way unless they are in the same sequence in both datasets.*  We can test the hypothesis for how `pos` is working by creating a dataset that is composed of the first few lines from `df` and the last few lines from `df`.  If our hypothesis is correct, then the first few lines should be okay, but the jitter will be different for the last few lines.  Let's test that out:

```
df_rep2 <- df[c(1:3, 8:10),]   # choosing first few and last few obs in df
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(position=pos) +
  geom_text_repel(data=df_rep2, aes(label=x), color='red', position=pos, force=20)
```

[image]

It should now be very apparent why the lines are not positioned the same way as the points in your example.

#### How to fix the issue

So what's the fix?  Well, we know that `pos` needs to be applied in the same sequence to the `geom_point()` and `geom_text_repel()` objects.  I wish there was a more elegant way to do this (and maybe there is), but you can avoid by using two separate calls to `geom_point()`: one matching the dataset used for `geom_text_repel()` and one that is "everything else".

At least, there's a good way of identifying "everything else", which is to use `anti_join()` from `dplyr`.  Here's the fix:

```
df_not <- anti_join(df, df_rep)  # find everything in df that is not df_rep
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(data=df_not, position=pos) +
  geom_point(data=df_rep, position=pos) +
  geom_text_repel(data=df[which(df$x>5),], aes(label=x), color='red', position=pos, force=20)
```

[image]